# Please explain this adafruit image for connecting a DS1307 RTC

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/3813

I understand that `analog 4` and `5` are `SDA/SLC`, isn't the picture also showing `5v` and `GND` being plugged into two analog pins? Does that work?

I have it wired up to the actual `5v` and `GND`, but it would be convieniet to be able to stack the RTC like they show in the picture

Comment: You can use ADC pins as general DIO too. In this case 2 PORTA pins set as output, one with HIGH and other LOW outputs to be used as source and sink. Sure pin currents must be within the allowed specs. DS1307 shall consume very low current (designed to be operating years by battery).

Comment: @Flanker You just gave an answer. You shouldn't put that in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's written in [the tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit/wiring-it-up)

> If you set analog pin 3 (digital 17) to an OUTPUT and HIGH and analog pin 2 (digital 16) to an OUTPUT and LOW you can power the RTC directly from the pins!

Comment: Wow I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!